# Word file corrupts after SaveAs

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've build a program to generate other docm files. The program works just fine without saving the generated files through VBA. When I do save through VBA with a SaveAs statement, however, the generated file becomes corrupt. Trying to open the file gives the following message:

```
"Could not open the file, there is a problem with the contents."
```

The SaveAs statement is as follows:

```
qDoc.SaveAs (getQuizURL(quizname))
```

The quizUrl function has been thoroughly tested and operates properly.

Does anyone know what's causing this and how to solve it? I could save it all manually, but given that other people will be using this program I'd like it to make it as friendly as possible.

Comment: Need to see the code which saves the doc.

Comment: I have added the statement above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing file format specification.

I am not sure about `SaveAs` either from your code.

I have got Office -2016 and it has a function called `SaveAs2`, but may be `SaveAs` is available in older versions.

Anyhow, change your code to specify the file format.

```
 ThisDocument.SaveAs2 "C:\temp\Test.docm", WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled
```

This will do the trick.

Comment: (Not sure if I should post as answer or not - just shedding some clarity) : I think in order for a macro to save a workbook, it must be saved as a macro enabled workbook, or binary may even work as well... I know writing a macro to save an macro enabled excel workbook works, but not the normal type.

Comment: Workbook? It's not related to excel